# Stored procedure delete records using user input (from parent and child table)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm on the last part of this assignment any help would be greatful thank you!

```
exec DeleteRecordWithUserInputCompanyName 'Costco'
```

It would say Command(s) completed successfully, however the rows was not deleted.

Task Stored procedure that will allow deletion of a customer given the company name as input.  Do not leave any “orphaned” records!

My Code

```
Create Procedure DeleteRecordWithUserInputCompanyName @CompanyName varchar(50)as
--Get All Company names
Declare @@CompanyNames varchar(50)
select @@CompanyNames = Company from Customers
--Get CustomerNumber mathing the company name
Declare @@CustomerNumber char(4)
select @@CustomerNumber = CustomerNo from Customers where Company = @CompanyName
--Get Order Number mathing Customer Number
Declare @@OrderNumber int
select @@OrderNumber = OrderNo from Orders where CustomerNo = @@CustomerNumber
if (@@CompanyNames = @CompanyName)
Begin
ALTER TABLE Customers NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
Delete from Customers where Company = @CompanyName
ALTER TABLE Customers CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
Delete from Orders where CustomerNo = @@CustomerNumber
ALTER TABLE SalesDetail NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL  
Delete from SalesDetail where OrderNo = @@OrderNumber
ALTER TABLE SalesDetail CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL  
End
```

Tables

```
Create Table Customers
(
CustomerNo char(4) 
Constraint ck_CustomerNoHas4positionsWithNumbers
Check(CustomerNo like'[0-9],[0-9],[0-9],[0-9]'),
Company varchar(50) not null,
CustomerRep char(3),
CreditLimt money default(20000.00),
PRIMARY KEY(CustomerNo)
)

Create Table Orders
(
OrderNo int,
OrderDate Date not null,
CustomerNo char(4) not null,
SalesRep char(3) not null
PRIMARY KEY(OrderNo)
)

Create Table SalesDetail
(
SaleDetailID int,
ManufactureID char(3) Constraint ck_ManufactureIDFromSaleDetails check(ManufactureID like'[a-z],[a-z],[a-z]') not null,
ProductID char(5) Constraint ck_ProductIDSalesDetail check(ProductID like'[0-9],[0-9],[a-z],[a-z],[a-z]') not null,
OrderNo int,
qtyOrdered int
PRIMARY KEY(SaleDetailID)
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select @@CompanyNames = Company from Customers
```

after this query `@@CompanyNames` Hold the Last Company in the table customers due to which the if condition is returning false, Hence inner block is not executed
Try This

```
Create Procedure DeleteRecordWithUserInputCompanyName @CompanyName varchar(50)as

Begin

--Delete Sale Detail First
Delete from SalesDetail where orderno in (select OrderNo from Orders where 
CustomerNo in (select CustomerNo from Customer where Company=@CompanyName))

--Delete From Orders Table
Delete from Orders where CustomerNo in (select CustomerNo from Customer where Company=@CompanyName)

--Delete Customers of that Company
Delete from Customer where Company=@companyName

End
```